# Python Quandl giving me error

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, quandl, zillow

So I have a bit of code in python which tries to get home prices from zillow. I am following the documentation exactly but I still get errors. The code:

```
import quandl

quandl.ApiConfig.api_key = "I have a key here in the code"

data = quandl.get("http://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/ZILL/S00022_A.csv", returns="numpy")
```

This, however, returns:

```
raise ValueError(Message.ERROR_COLUMN_INDEX_TYPE % dataset)
ValueError: The column index must be expressed as an integer for http://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/ZILL/S00022_A.csv.
```

What does this mean and how do I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: please post the error in its entirety

Comment: I'm sorry. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

The code quandl.get() goes with the installed csv file and not an URL. So please import a dataset code and try to import it in your code by

```
quandl.get('WIKI/GOOGL')
```

Here, I have imported a dataset for stock prediction of Google